# JOIN the table in each element in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

This is what my controller currently looks like, which returns the following result:

```
exports.getSenderdata = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.senderId;
  Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
      id_sender: userId,
    },
    attributes: [
      'amount_money',
      'date_time',
      'transfer_title',
      'id_recipient',
      'id_sender',
    ],
  }).then(transactions => {
    res.send(transactions);
  });
};
```

// results:

```
 [
  {
    "amount_money": 5,
    "date_time": "2019-01-19T20:15:07.000Z",
    "transfer_title": "test",
    "id_recipient": 2,
    "id_sender": 1
  },
  {
    "amount_money": 2,
    "date_time": "2019-01-19T20:20:10.000Z",
    "transfer_title": "payment example",
    "id_recipient": 2,
    "id_sender": 1
  }
]
```

I would like to include a different table to each element in json, that `id_recipient` on this results = `id` in different table. so I would like this result > Is this something possible?

```
[
  {
    "amount_money": 5,
    "date_time": "2019-01-19T20:15:07.000Z",
    "transfer_title": "test",
    "id_recipient": 2,
    "id_sender": 1
    "user": {
      "name": "Claudie"
    }
  },
  {
    "amount_money": 2,
    "date_time": "2019-01-19T20:20:10.000Z",
    "transfer_title": "payment example",
    "id_recipient": 2,
    "id_sender": 1
    "user": {
      "name": "John"
    }
  }
]
```

I have a solution that I need: I want to send this string, I do not know how.

```
    exports.getRecipientdata = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.recipientId;
  const sendersArray = [];
  Transaction.findAll({
    where: {
      id_sender: userId,
    },
  })
    .then(transactions =>
      Promise.all(
        transactions.map(({ id_recipient }) =>
          User.findAll({
            where: {
              id: id_recipient,
            },
            attributes: ['name', 'surname'],
            include: [
              {
                model: Transaction,
                where: { id_sender: db.Sequelize.col('user.id') },
                attributes: [
                  'amount_money',
                  'date_time',
                  'transfer_title',
                  'id_recipient',
                  'id_sender',
                ],
              },
            ],
          })
            .then(sender => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(sender)); // <- this is string, i need this to send res
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            }),
        ),
      ),
    )
    .then(() => {
// ?
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    .then(sender => {
      sendersArray.push(sender);
    })
```

Try:

```
    .then(sender => {
      sendersArray.push(sender);
      if (sendersArray.length == transactions.length)
         res.send(sendersArray);
    })
```

and remove the `res.send(sendersArray);` at the end.

`Promise.all` should work something like this:

```
.then(transactions =>
  Promise.all(
    transactions.map(({ id_recipient }) => { return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      User.findAll({
        where: {
          id: id_recipient,
        },
        attributes: ['name', 'surname'],
        include: [
          {
            model: Transaction,
            where: { id_sender: db.Sequelize.col('user.id') },
            attributes: [
              'amount_money',
              'date_time',
              'transfer_title',
              'id_recipient',
              'id_sender',
            ],
          },
        ],
      })
        .then(sender => {
          resolve(JSON.stringify(sender)); // <- this is string, i need this to send res
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        }),
    })}),
  ),
)
.then((results) => {
  res.send(results);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. I can use a promise too, but I have a problem with results, because I return double the same select. why?